# Intellij Community - MacOS - JDK setup

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea

I can't figure out why Intellij fails to resolve basic Classes such as String?

Tried invalidating cache and restarting - doesn't help).

My Setup:

- Intellij IDEA Community Edition 15.0.2
- jdk-8u65-macosx-x64

  [image: My SDK config]
  [image]

[image]

Still basic Classes like String are not resolved.

[image]

Comment: Why Intellij fails to resolve basic Classes?

Comment: I solved it by: 
* removing all setting files (as per :  [link](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs)   ) 
** this included all previous versions of Intellij (in my case 13, 13 community and 15 community) ..
* after that started intellij and followed wizard with everything set to default
* created new project and added SDK from suggested path (which is exactly the same as I posted on the screenshot)
* my current project config is identical to what it was when I had the problem

Comment: clue to delete all cached settings was thanks to fact that exactly same setup worked on my work Mac where I never had Intellij installed before

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes invalidating cache and restarting will work

Comment: it worked for me as well

Comment: tried this, doesn't help